# What is the original meaning of P and V operations in a context of a semaphore?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, semaphore

Does anybody know why semaphore operations are called P and V? Every time I read a chapter on semaphores it says something like the following:

In order for the thread to obtain a resource it executes a P operation. And in order for the thread to release a resource it executes a V operation.

What does P and V stand for? Why they are not called wait and signal?

Comment: The relevant wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Function_name_etymology) has a section called Function name etymology. Short explanation: There are lots of people who don't use English.

Comment: @Bill: Not sure if they named P and V because of not everybody use English - because anyhow computer's language is the English, and all programming languages are in English... or at least most of them - not sure if there is any written or use other languages. So someone that has reach to the level of learning/studying the semaphores wouldn't stuck on the naming of signal/wait and would need a P and V to understand/make use of them. That wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @Sbpro "Computer's language is the English." Today's prevalence of English is just the result of a long-term shake-out. Things were different in the 1960s, when Dijkstra wrote his paper. For example, [ALGOL 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68) was designed with internationalization in mind. See also: [Non-English-based programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages). You may like the fact there are even Greek programming languages.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Dijkstra, one of the inventors of semaphores, used P and V. The letters come from the Dutch words Probeer (try) and Verhoog (increment).

See also: https://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/os/resources/origin_of_PV.html

Comment: "Probeer te verlagen" is "try to decrease". "Verhogen" is increase.

Answer (score 7):

@Kris answer is just partially right.

V stands for 'Verhoog' and P stands for 'Prolaag', not 'Probeer' as cited [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eyap/classes/os/resources/origin_of_PV.html).

Verhoog can be translated as 'increasing'. Decreasing would be 'Verlaag', but for better distinction between the letters Dijkstra invented the word 'Prolaag'.

See the naming in the [original paper](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eyap/classes/os/resources/EWD74.pdf).

Comment: This is indeed true, I'm dutch and my professor told me he only says `Probeer` to prevent students asking the same question every week on the meaning of `Prolagg` :D

Comment: Good catch on "Prolaag".

Answer (score 1):

V stands for signal and P stands for wait.

You can check the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) for details.

[image]

> Why they are not called wait and signal?

I would agree with Bill on this, the most likely reason is that because there are a lot of people who dont use English, so its probably because of that it is not called wait and signal.

Comment: Not sure if they named P and V because of not everybody use English - because anyhow computer's language is the English, and all programming languages are in English... or at least most of them - not sure if there is any written or use other languages. So someone that has reach to the level of learning/studying the semaphores wouldn't stuck on the naming of signal/wait and would need a P and V to understand/make use of them.

Answer (score 0):

- V stands for 'Verhoog', which can be translated as "increment".
- P stands for 'Prolaag', a madeup Dutch word of 'probeer verlaag', which can be translated as "try to decrease".

Source: C# 4.0 Unleashed
https://books.google.es/books?id=TDEsRmRMPNkC&pg=PT2060&lpg=PT2060&dq=prolaag+in+dutch&source=bl&ots=EnxjFiuZTA&sig=ACfU3U0zxBQju4Ob6Wk449Z7XZK_NH4ZSA&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0lq3FhqX2AhXXhf0HHTqPDbkQ6AF6BAgDEAM