# Understanding an exam answer on Semaphores

Tags: semaphore

This question came up in a practice exam. I do not really understand how they got to the answers that they said are correct.

I was hoping for some help understanding the question and how to answer it?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand what P and V do ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29#Operation_names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606162/what-is-the-original-meaning-of-p-and-v-operations-in-a-context-of-a-semaphore

Comment: I do now i have read the links you have provided

Comment: Good. Do you then understand what the correct answers are and why?

Comment: No i still do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it all comes to this:

wait (P): If the value of semaphore variable is not negative, decrements it by 1. **If the semaphore variable is now negative, the process executing wait is blocked** (i.e., added to the semaphore's queue) until the value is greater or equal to 1. Otherwise, the process continues execution, having used a unit of the resource.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) and [More information](https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/SEMA/basics.html)

For the correct answers:

**1)** Since the semaphore is initially equal 0, thread 3 will block on P(S) waiting for another thread to do V(S). This will only happen on thread 1, and after A is completed. So no matter how long statement A takes to execute, thread 3 will wait until the instruction V(S) is executed. So A will always be executed before F.

**2)** The same concept applies with B and G. Before G you have to execute P(T) and this will wait for an instruction V(T). This only happens after B has been executed.

**3)** Since A is executed before F as demonstrated in (1), and F is always executed before G, A is always executed before G.

---

As for the incorrect answers:

**a)** A is executed before E? Maybe, but not always. Because thread 1 and thread 2 have to wait for a semaphore, thread 2 could execute B, V(T) and E faster than A, so in this case the sentence (a) is false.

**b)** B is executed before F? Maybe, but not always. Why? To execute F, thread 3 only depends on thread 1 (the semaphore S) so C and A can execute very fast and then go to F while B can be still executing because it is very slow.

**d)** C is executed before D? Maybe, but not always. Again, C might take a long time to execute and thread 1, since it has not to wait for any semaphore, could execute all its instructions very fast, before C is completed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me get my head round it

Comment: Is everything clear or do you want me to elaborate a bit further? Don't carry any questions : ) better clarify them now